# How to use $http.head() to check if some resource exists

Tags: angularjs, rest

I would like to introduce a HEAD Web API endpoint that will send 200 if a resource exists or 404 if it doesn't.

`HEAD api/resource/{id}`

How this can be handled in AngularJS $http.head() without the need of boiler plate code to check the status so it returns true or false? Or is it that 200 will be considered success and 404 failure? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Michail

Comment: What do you mean by boiler plate code?

Comment: The same code over and over to check the status that head returned.. Except if 404 is considered failure and 200 a success

Comment: This is what services are for.

Comment: simple service is all you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found it.. From the documentation

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success
>   status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that
>   if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently
>   follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such
>   responses.

```
$http.head('/api/resource/'+someId, config).then(
   function() { return true;}, 
   function() { return false;}
);
```

[$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)